# Unicorn rails server with Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, latency, unicorn

I'm looking for the best setup to use in conjunction with Unicorn. Are there clear advantages or disadvantages to using Unicorn rails server with Apache? Should I consider using NGINX?

I'm concerned most with low latency, and my current setup has rather high latency around 300 ms.

My stack looks like the following:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Ruby 2.0
- Rails 4.0
- Postgres
- Redis
- Apache2
- Unicorn

Answer (score 0):

I find nginx and unicorn to be a nearly perfect match.

nginx is much smaller than apache, and is designed to do a few things very well rather than all things possible.

My setup is basically what you describe, other than I have selected nginx over apache for the above reasons.